# The requested URL /pub/ was not found on this server. - Magento .htaccess problem

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, htaccess, .htaccess, magento2.4.2

I have an problem about magento 2.4.2
Installed magento 2.4.2 using Composer-CLI. But I can't access magento homepage (http://localhost:8888/magento2)

The requested URL /pub/ was not found on this server.

[image]

**My .htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/setup/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
RewriteRule .* /pub/$0 [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

**Changed .htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/setup/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
RewriteRule .* pub/$0 [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

If I change the RewriteRule from .* /pub/$0 [L] to .* pub/$0 [L] , i can see magento home page with some errors.

The page you requested was not found, and we have a fine guess why.
If you typed the URL directly, please make sure the spelling is correct.
If you clicked on a link to get here, the link is outdated.

[image]

**How can solve this problem?**

Comment: Change your webroot to the "pub" directory in the apache config file.

Comment: @AmitSaini How to do ? Please show here or post your answer.

Comment: @Said Setup apache document root like this https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html#1-edit-your-server-configuration

Comment: Using RewriteRule .* pub/$0 [L] instead of RewriteRule .* /pub/$0 [L] worked for me... Home page is getting loaded properly but all inner pages are throwing error like 404

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is already known issue when using 2.4.2 for the first time and with a setup that doesn't point to /pub folder (**the webserver *doesn't know* that it has to serve the requests from the /pub folder**)

I suggest you create a virtual host dedicated solely to your magento 2.4.2 instance:

1. enter/ create the Apache config by running `vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`
2. **update the 'DocumentRoot' directive to point to 'pub' folder** (note that you need to replace '/var/www/html/magento2ce' with the path to your magento installation):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
         ServerName magento.local
         ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
         DocumentRoot /var/www/html/magento2ce/pub

         ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
         CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

         <Directory "/var/www/html">
               AllowOverride all
         </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

3.a. if you didn't have the virtual host, then run `sudo a2ensite 000-default.conf`, otherwise, skip this step.

3.b. restart Apache by running  `systemctl restart apache2` command

3.c. if you didnt have the virtual host before, then add the new website to your hosts `vim /etc/hosts` and add the line `127.0.0.1 magento.local` inside it

4. update the magento base URL - I see you appended a directory name to your server’s hostname when you installed Magento (`http://localhost:8888/magento2`), you’ll need to remove it and change it to the virtual host name. This can be achieved by logging into the database and running the command:

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value='http://magento.local/' WHERE path='web/unsecure/base_url';
UPDATE core_config_data SET value='http://magento.local/' WHERE path='web/secure/base_url';
```

5. make sure you are serving the requests from the 'pub' folder by checking the 'env.php' file, it should contain the following piece:

```
'directories' => [
    'document_root_is_pub' => true
]
```

<sub>Source: the documentation https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html.</sub>

Comment: Please give solution not link

Comment: I updated my answer, but surely if someones checks the link will find the same steps.

Comment: I install in to my local pc and there are so many magento installed, so how to manage multiple magento setup with magento 2.4.2

Comment: for the m2.4.2 install you will have to have a dedicated virtual host

Comment: i am not understanding what you say. please explain bit more.

Comment: just follow my instructions above. you need to have a dedicated virtual host for your m2.4.2 installation and not run it like 'http://localhost/magento2'. if you don't create a separate virtual host, then all other installations will cease to work.

Comment: @DianaBotean thank u so much it worked great

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Virtual Hosts following this instruction: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-18-04-quickstart