# css not getting loaded while upgrading to 2.4.2

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.4.2

i have upgraded magento 2.2.6 to magento 2.4.2 successfully
But css is not getting reflected

[image]

I am able to login successfully. But not able to find the solution.

I have made dev/static/sign = 0
reindexing done
setup-content:deploy -f done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that your webserver serves the requests from the proper location. it should be referencing the **`<magento_proj_root>/pub` folder as Document Root.**

[image]

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html

---

***Later edit***

Also see this thread where I explained the settings for URLs when using a virtual host [The requested URL /pub/ was not found on this server. - Magento .htaccess problem](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/332091/the-requested-url-pub-was-not-found-on-this-server-magento-htaccess-proble)

Comment: i tried but still no output

Comment: what's the format of your Magento URL? is it something like `http://<domain.name>/magento` or `http://<domain.name>/<folder_name>`?

Comment: http://<domain.name>/<folder_name>

Comment: you will have to change your urls and remove the <folder_name> from it. go to the database or the admin and update the secure/unsecure url settings. also make sure the same url is used at webserver level in the 'servername' directive. see the update on my answer, i added a link there that might help you.

Comment: you're most welcome :) cheers!