# Magento 2 Scandi PWA theme shows admin panel and frontend without styles

Tags: magento2, theme, pwa-theme

so I have been struggling installing Scandi PWA on Magento 2.4.2.

I have managed to get to the final step, where you just need to select the theme on admin panel like documentation says:

```
Run the upgrade command and disable full-page caching:
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento cache:disable full_page
It is now time to enable the new theme. In the Magento admin panel, navigate to Content > Design > Configuration. Edit the scope you want to change (typically the most general one in the list), and select the new theme. Finally, flush the cache:
bin/magento cache:flush
```

But I can't choose the theme because my admin panel looks without styles and javascript.

I have tried to run every command Magento has

```
setup:upgrade
setup:static-content:deploy
setup:di:compile
cache:clean
cache:flush
indexer:reindex
```

even clean the cache of scandi pwa with

```
php bin/magento scandipwa:pq:flush
```

but nothing seems to work, I don't know what could cause this error

Official documentation: https://docs.scandipwa.com/getting-started/getting-started/magento-integration

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Magento installation serves requests from the **`'<magento_root>/pub'`** folder. Please read this thread for more details (I explained more there) - [css not getting loaded while upgrading to 2.4.2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/332159/css-not-getting-loaded-while-upgrading-to-2-4-2)