# Magento 2.4.2 Window10 localhost Xampp 404 not found

Tags: localhost, xampp, magento2.4.2, not-found, windows10

I just installed Magento 2, it shown the success page result however the homepage and admin is not found.

[image]

404 Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1j PHP/7.4.16 Server at localhost Port 80

[image]
[image]

Magento 2.4.2
Window10 64
XAMPP 3.2.4
Elasticsearch-7.11.2
Composer 2.0.11

Answer (score 8):

**Step 1: -**

We need to set document root to pub, to do this go to file **C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/magento24/pub"
    ServerName yourname.magento.com
</VirtualHost>
```

paste this code at the bottom of the file.

yourname.magento.com - this is domain name which you set as per your wish. So now you need to access magento frontend and admin with base url "yourname.magento.com".

**Step 2:-**

Now lets edit C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts   file and add the below line at the bottom of the file.

```
 127.0.0.1  yourname.magento.com
```

**Step 3: - Update the base URL:**

Go to our magento database and run below command

```
  UPDATE core_config_data SET value='http://yourname.magento.com/' WHERE path='web/unsecure/base_url';
```

**Step 4:-**   Update the app/etc/env.php file

The following node needs to be appended to the env.php file.

```
'directories' => [
    'document_root_is_pub' => true
 ]
```

**Step 5 : -**  Switch to developer mode.

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hurray !!! All done .... Lets check your

homepage http://yourname.magento.com/ and

admin page http://yourname.magento.com/admin

Comment: Your solution is the most perfect, it really works normally. I want to give you 100 likes.

Comment: Thank You Angelo. I am happy that it helped you.

Comment: I don't undestand, why I can not use http://localhost/magento2 ?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a Magento issue, most likely your question will be closed.

This seems to be a XAMPP issue. You will have to set up a virtual host in your XAMPP.

Learn how to setup Virtual Host in your XAMPP here: https://www.wpwhitesecurity.com/multiple-websites-xampp/

After setting virtual host, don't forget to add your domain in to your hosts file.
https://www.wpwhitesecurity.com/windows-hosts-file/

Comment: Thanks Adarsh Khatri, I updated the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by the fact that you don't have a dedicated virtual host for your magento installation. **As of Magento 2.4.2, the document root has to be point to the `<magento_root>/pub` folder otherwise you won't be able to access your shop's frontend or backend properly.**

So if you don't have a dedicated virtual host, you can't tell your webserve how to serve the requests from the /pub folder.

Please follow this thread [frontend and admin not working magento 2.4.2 upgrade](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/332400/frontend-and-admin-not-working-magento-2-4-2-upgrade) in order to solve the issue, I gave more details there and the other comments and answers are also helpful.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

estou tentanto instalar o magento 2 no win 10 sem sucesso, alguém pode me dizer o passo a passo da instalação? Obrigadu!

Comment: You should use English to reply. Otherwise no one understand.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create .htaccess file on your root and copy that from Magento 2 directory [CLICK HERE FOR THE FILE](https://github.com/magento/magento2) choose the version that you are using. Then create .htaccess inside pub and copy that also.

It will work fine

Run the below command:

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade && sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile && sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f && sudo chmod 777 -R pub/* var/* generated/* && sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not always necessary to change the host:

> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

It would also be enough to simply use a subdomain for localhost:

> D:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/magento2/pub"
    ServerName magento2.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart Apache after changes

Magento Config:
web/unsecure/base_url = http://magento2.localhost/