# Magento 2.4 is loading from pub folder not root folder

Tags: magento2

I am have installed Magento 2.4 successfully. I don't know why it's loading from the pub folder, not the root folder. I have followed all the document still not working.

The links I have followed
https://firebearstudio.com/blog/magento-2-css-and-javascript-files-are-not-loading.html,
[Magento 2 CSS and JavaScript not loading from correct folder](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97209/magento-2-css-and-javascript-not-loading-from-correct-folder).

Still no USE. CSS and Javascript file even admin URL also not loading. Can anyone help to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check my answer which I mention?

Comment: Magento 2.4.2 now loads by default from the *magento_root/pub* folder.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1: -**

We need to set document root to pub, to do this go to file **C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/magento2/pub"
    ServerName yourname.magento.com
</VirtualHost>
```

paste this code at the bottom of the file.

yourname.magento.com - this is domain name which you set as per your wish. So now you need to access magento frontend and admin with base url "yourname.magento.com".

**Step 2:-**

Now lets edit C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts   file and add the below line at the bottom of the file.

```
 127.0.0.1  yourname.magento.com
```

**Step 3: - Update the base URL:**

Go to our magento database and run below command

```
  UPDATE core_config_data SET value='http://yourname.magento.com/' WHERE path='web/unsecure/base_url';
```

**Step 4:-**   Update the app/etc/env.php file

The following node needs to be appended to the env.php file.

```
'directories' => [
    'document_root_is_pub' => true
 ]
```

**Step 5 : -**  Switch to developer mode.

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Now check your frontend and backend.

Comment: Thanks, Sonal. Big help

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It should be loaded from pub for security. Webserver doc root should be changed to pub.

Review https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html

or similar topics:

[Magento 2.4.2 Window10 localhost Xampp 404 not found](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/333348/magento-2-4-2-window10-localhost-xampp-404-not-found/333369#333369)

[404 Not Found after fresh Magento 2.4.2 installation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/331840/404-not-found-after-fresh-magento-2-4-2-installation)