# after install magento 2.4.2 frontend and backend url not working

Tags: magento2.4.2, xampp, php-7.4

I have installed Magento version 2.4.2 in xampp ubuntu with elastic search,

installation was successful, but when i run front URL and backend URL, its not working,
both URL's shows below error,

> Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. If
> you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404
> 127.0.0.1 Apache/2.4.46 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1h PHP/7.4.13 mod_perl/2.0.11 Perl/v5.32.0

[image]
so i have chacked in Database **core_config_data** table, here is shows same URL name
http://127.0.0.1/magento242/,

after installation, i have run Magento's all basic commands also,

now please help me on this, how can i fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: have you set up your virtual host to point to the magento /pub directory? see this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/333541/90298 and dev docs reference https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html

Comment: hello @bernieu2 i have tried as u suggest but its not worked.

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/magento242/pub/ it displays files?