# Getting 404 on front end and back end after installed Magento 2.4.2 in XAMPP, Windows 10 HOw to fix these

Tags: xampp, magento2.4.2

I'm new in magento and need to fix these issue

error appears - "Not Found

The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1h PHP/7.4.15 Server at localhost Port 80"

appears 404 on front end and back-end also

OS: Windows 10,

Xampp v3.2.4,

Composer tried both v1 & v2,

Mangento Version: 2.4.2,

elasticsearch-7.11.2,

please help to get these fix!!!!

Answer (score 0):

you must configure a virtual host for your magento installation and make sure the document root set in your apache configuration points to `<magento_root>/pub` folder.

Check this thread [frontend and admin not working magento 2.4.2 upgrade](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/332400/frontend-and-admin-not-working-magento-2-4-2-upgrade) for more details.