# Magento 2.4.2 on subfolder with Apache

Tags: magento2, htaccess, magento2.4.2

Magento with 2.4.2 changed the location of the root and the index.php by set everything inside the pub folder.
This causes a 404 problem in the case magento is not in the docroot and I cannot resolve it.

I currently have this situation:

docroot website.com

```
public_html. (docroot)
    |
     -- store
          |  
           -- pub
```

I tried to change .htaccess on public_html and on store but all possible combinations and solutions do not seem to bring results

Magento return always 404 error whatever url i request
website.com/store/ or website.com/store/category ecc..

Static files return also 404 but if i create manually a static file (example print.css o style.css), this file is loaded correctly.
It would seem that the rewrite rules work for files but not for magento (and its rules for generating static files in developer mode)

Using "index.php" in the url like this
website.com/store/index.php/category/

allows magento to load the page (but static files not)

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Check this thread [frontend and admin not working magento 2.4.2 upgrade](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/332400/frontend-and-admin-not-working-magento-2-4-2-upgrade) especially the answer provided by @iphigenie. Worth a try.