# Magento 2.4 : Frontend/Backend Not working

Tags: php, javascript, css, magento2.4, static-content-deploy

I am using below configuration :

Magento 2.4.x

PHP 7.4

Composer 2.0

Frontend and Backend is not working. All .htaccess files are there in required folder.

But still,I am getting below log in apache

```
GET /magento2/static/version1619677973/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Magento_Theme/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 39962 "http://127.0.0.1/magento2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.72 Safari/537.36"
OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 488 "http://127.0.0.1/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.72 Safari/537.36"
```

[image]

Also notice in console that, pub folder is not considered.

Need Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert the below four rows in the core_config_data table

| Path | Value |
| --- | --- |
| web/secure/base_static_url | {{store_url}}/pub/static/ |
| web/unsecure/base_static_url | {{store_url}}/pub/static/ |
| web/secure/base_media_url | {{store_url}}/m242/pub/media/ |
| web/unsecure/base_media_url | {{store_url}}/pub/media/ |

php bin/magento cache:flush

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your webserver uses as document root the `<magento_folder>/pub` folder when serving the requests.

See [frontend and admin not working magento 2.4.2 upgrade](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/332400/frontend-and-admin-not-working-magento-2-4-2-upgrade) for more details on how to solve this.