# Styles are not loading in Magento 2.4.2 on Mac OS

Tags: css, magento2.4.2, styles, less-compilation, macbook

I have installed vanilla (with sample data) Magento Community edition 2.4.2 on Mac OS with following technology stack however styles are not loaded at all, not even in head block. However I can see all CSS files in pub/static folder when content is deployed. As it can be seen in attached screenshot, there are NO errors in browser console as well.

[image]

Web server: Nginx

PHP: 7.4 with fpm

Elastic Search: v7

Mysql: 5.7.32 (Here I agree that on Magento's site Mysql 8 is recommended but with same version on linux, it works as expected.)

Comment: pcre.jit=0 is solution to php 7.4

Answer (score 2):

You can try this if you have configured nginx correctly:

If you use php **7.4.20**

Edit that php.ini file and find the section `[Pcre]` and add this line at the bottom of that section :

```
pcre.jit=0
```

Restart your PHP

see : [Magento doesn't include theme.css in html](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/339914/magento-doesnt-include-theme-css-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are serving the requests from the `<magento_root>/pub` folder at webserver level.

Comment: Thanks Diana for your response. Considering https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html#a-note-about-nginx, I am already using 'nginx.conf.sample' in Nginx server block which changes root to <magento_root>/pub.
However I tried with approach that you suggested which gives 404.
Any more detail around it would be helpful.

Comment: hi there, check this thread, maybe you will find something useful in there https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/332400/frontend-and-admin-not-working-magento-2-4-2-upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Within this URL - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html - under the Operating Systems section - this is shared for your consideration.  "Magento is not supported on Microsoft Windows and macOS."