# Magento2 store not running on localhost .htaccess file problem

Tags: magento2.4.2

I have a magento2.4 store running on server. I installed it on localhost but it give 404 error.
[image]

It has a strange .htaccess file contents.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/setup/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
RewriteRule .* /pub/$0 [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

If i change the .htaccess file content to a standard M2 .htaccess than it gives directory content.
[image]

Can you suggest some solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem you are facing is due to the new rules of M2.4.2 which will now serve all requests from the `<magento_root>/pub` folder. This is kind of incompatible with what you are trying to do - launching Magento from a folder directly in browser without a dedicated virtual host.

You have 2 options:

1. Create a dedicated virtual host and set the `DocumentRoot` to point to the `<magento_root>/pub` folder - for this approach check my answer in this thread [The requested URL /pub/ was not found on this server. - Magento .htaccess problem](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/332091/the-requested-url-pub-was-not-found-on-this-server-magento-htaccess-proble)
2. Try to make Magento accept that you are not having a dedicated virtual host and adapt the Apache instructions - and for this approach I suggest you read the answers given by me and @iphigenie in the thread [frontend and admin not working magento 2.4.2 upgrade](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/332400/frontend-and-admin-not-working-magento-2-4-2-upgrade)

Good Luck!

Comment: in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf, i changed DocumentRoot /var/www/html/m2-dogdream/pub and restarted apache, than site was accessed by http://127.0.0.1 only.

Answer (score 1):

After Installed magento 2.4 version your localhost support with /pub directory like `{localhostname}/pub/index.php`

We can access without pub directory follow below steps

**1.** Copy .httaccess file from pub folder and override it to root .htaccess file

**2.** Upload pub/index.php file to root magento directory

**3.** Add below code in app/etc/env.php file

```
'system' => [
    'default' => [
        'web' => [
            'unsecure' => [
                'base_media_url' => '{{secure_base_url}}pub/media/',
                'base_static_url' => '{{secure_base_url}}pub/static/'
            ],
            'secure' => [
                'base_media_url' => '{{secure_base_url}}pub/media/',
                'base_static_url' => '{{secure_base_url}}pub/static/'
            ]
        ]
    ]
],
```