# magento2 admin page 404 error

Tags: magento2, 404

I am Patrick and a super beginner. my Magento2 admin page shows a 404 error(whoops, our bad...).

windows 10, xampp 3.2.4, php 7.3.27, magento 2.4.2., phpmyadmin.

and I changed apache port 80 to 8888, 443 to 8889. I put localhost:8888 of course.

I installed it with the sample successfully.

and I put '/pub/' in my domain using my DB table core_config_data(web/unsecure/base_url). Before I did

it, every page was a 404 error. Thanks to '/pub/', I could have saved a first sample page. Only the first page.(localhost:8888/mymagentoname/pub/ - It shows the first page well.)

But when I try to enter the admin page or others (ex. gear - bag) show me a 404 error.

domain/Index.php also makes a 404 error.

that lists are what I've done to resolve the 404 error,

1. Cache clean and flush(cmd)
2. Reindex(cmd)
3. deploy -f(cmd)
4. Check admin URL again(env.php)
5. AllowOverride All(httpd.conf)

Whatever you comment, it would be helping me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that apache points to <magento_root>/pub folder, for example `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/magento2/pub`.

Comment: If you don't mind, would you explain to me in more detail, please? Like how do I check what apache is pointing now and if it is wrong, how can i change it. Thank you

Comment: can you please check this? there are more details here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/335207/35330

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try it

Answer (score 0):

magento version and php version not matched . You can check  [this link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html)